# Make navbar transparent only when on top of the page and then plain background when scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I know there are a few topics related to making a transparent navigation bar but the answers were not as I expected.

I would like to make a navigation bar whose features are similar to this site:
http://themenectar.com/demo/salient-frostwave/

I mean the bar will be transparent when it is on top of the page. As soon as you scroll down, it still sticks to the top but it now has a visible background.

So, how to deal with the problem with HTML, CSS and JavaScript/jQuery?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think that using the `opacity` CSS attribute should do it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a plugin called [headroom.js](http://wicky.nillia.ms/headroom.js/) 
It's extremely easy to use and to implement.

All you would have to do is to change the background-color of your nav-bar or header once it isn't "stuck" to the top of the page anymore.

The plugin is lightweight too, and comes in either vanilla js, jquery and can even be used easily with angular.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
   if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
       $('element here').css(css goes here );
   }
});
if($('html').offset().top) {
  //If on top
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To make it transparent while on the top of the page, it would be more or less like this:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if($("#nav-bar").scrollTop() == 0 && $("#nav-bar").css("opacity") != 1 ){
      $( "#nav-bar" ).css("opacity", 0.5);
    }else if( $("#nav-bar").scrollTop() != 0 && $("#nav-bar").css("opacity") != 0.5 ){
      $( "#nav-bar" ).css("opacity", 1);
    }

});
```